# RAM limited to 12GB by motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3, memory-limit

I want to add more RAM to my motherboard (ASUS P6T) and I was looking through the manual and found this under the specifications:

[image: Memory specifications]

I'm guessing this means 12GB total? I asked somebody else and he told me that it be better to check what the chipset (Intel X58) supports. I did a Google found that some are saying they have 24GB of RAM (some actually say they got 48GB) installed with the Intel X58 chipset. I currently have 6GB of RAM installed, so if I had another 6GB of RAM will that be it? Or can I add more than 6GB of RAM?

Comment: If your manual indicates only 12GB, but online indicates 24GB support, you may need to update your BIOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern consumer systems, the chipset doesn't have any impact on how much memory you can put in a system. The memory controller (formerly "North Bridge") is actually on the processor die now.

The limiting factor here is really how many channels your CPU supports, and how many they've actually "wired up" to DIMM sockets.

This [ASUS P6T page](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P6T/#specifications) indicates 24 GB max.

Comment: So then can you please elaborate on why the [online manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1366/P6T/E4283_P6T-manual.zip) is different from their website (besides the fact that the manual is outdated)?

Comment: Probably because the manual is outdated. Processors change over time, and if the manufacturer doesn't update the manual, then it'll have old information e.g. the maximum memory possible at the time of writing.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it to work on 14GB RAM. I had to juggle the RAM sticks around to get to work though. I guess the downfall about having dual or triple channel memory, is each slot needs to have the same RAM capacity. For example, if slot #1 has 4GB RAM than slot #2 needs 4GB RAM as well. Now if I want to had more RAM, then it needs to be either a 2GB or 8GB stick.